# Dynamical splines library for C++

Tags: c++, spline, curves, bspline

i am having a lot of datapoints (e.g: 1000) which display the lanes of the road. I am also getting new Datapoints for the same location (more measurement for same point) and for the next Datapoints. So i am getting the flow of the Datapoints. I want approximate this datapoints with an Cubiq Spline.
For this i would need an splines library which would allow me to update my road and giving me my Cubiq Polinoms (maybe i can say 20 Datapoints = 1 Polynom or better way dynamicly...like if the road is not having any curvs...its only 1 polynom  and if its having a lot of curvs...i am having a lot of polynoms).

Do you know any Lib, which could be usefull for me?

Thanks

best regards

Nikolai

Comment: seems like you didnt read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting. Asking for libraries is explicitly off topic (4.)

Comment: You want some kind of curvature metric, such as the second derivative, which will help you segment the splines. You could do this yourself and have more fun along the way.  Otherwise start searching, because as already mentioned your question does not fit the purpose of StackOverflow.